# como solicitar ao Make que somente execute uma target após o termino de outra quando usando multicore

Tags: multi-core, make

**ATUALIZADO**

Ao executar o make com a opção -j para usar multicore ou seja colocar cada target solicitando em um core, ele não respeita a ordem sendo que executa as duas simultaneamente.

Por exemplo

make Objeto1 Objeto2 -j4

Ele irá executar o `Objeto1` e as targets associadas a ele simulteamente `Objeto2` e as targets associadas a ele, se por algum motivo uma das targets interferir no produto que será usada pelas demais em execução terei um conflito.

No momento o que tenho tido como problema esta ligado a target clean, que as vezes limpa um objeto que foi criado.

O uso de chamadas sequências como `make Objeto1 && make Objeto2` não me deixa aproveitar o recurso para uso dos múltiplos cores do processador, o que seria a mesma coisa que chamar o comando make sem a chave `-j4`, ou seja seria o mesmo que chamar `make Objeto1 Objeto2`

Answer (score 0):

Rode o make sequencialmente:

```
make -j4 clean; make -j4 all
```

Update:

Pode-se fazer alguma coisa assim:

```
all: clean real_all
    @echo ended all

clean:
    @echo cleaning...

real_all: target1 target2 ...
    @echo ended real_all

target1: ...
    ...
    @echo ended target1

target2: ...
    ...
    @echo ended target2
```

Eu acho isso gambiarra, acho melhor rodar sequencialmente como mostrei acima.

Comment: Bem talvez não tenha sido feliz no exemplo, mas a ideia é que seja apenas digitando um make e gerenciando internamente as dependências. Vou elaborar melhor a pergunta.

Comment: X, tentei melhorar a explanação do problema, 
Sua proposta ainda não resolve minha situação. Já tenho uma target clean_all que limpa e compila em seguida.